# Высота дроби, оптимизация кода

Tags: python, оптимизация, арифметика

Высота обыкновенной дроби — это сумма модуля числителя и знаменателя этой дроби. Высота рационального числа — это сумма модуля числителя и знаменателя несократимой обыкновенной дроби, соответствующей этому числу. Надо написать программу, которая напечатает все рациональные числа высотой n (её значение введёт пользователь), лежащие между 0 и 1.

Вот один из вариантов такой программы:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Функция нахождения наибольшего общего делителя"""
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

# Запрашиваем у пользователя высоту
height = int(input("Введите высоту рациональных чисел: "))

# Перебираем все возможные значения числителей
for numerator in range(1, height):
    denominator = height - numerator
    # Проверяем, что дробь несократимая
    if gcd(numerator, denominator) != 1:
        continue
    # Проверяем, что дробь лежит между 0 и 1
    if numerator/denominator > 1 or numerator/denominator < 0:
        continue
    # Если все условия выполнены, печатаем дробь
    print(f"{numerator}/{denominator}")
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, этот код оптимизировать. Например, в данном варианте на каждом шаге цикла производится проверка несократимости дроби, а также проверка на возлежание дроби между 0 и 1. Может, можно как-то уменьшить количество таких проверок?

P. S.

Девятилетняя ученица одной из моих знакомых вообще использовала два цикла вместо одного, но в её возрасте такое простительно:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Функция нахождения наибольшего общего делителя"""
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

# Запрашиваем у пользователя высоту
height = int(input("Введите высоту рациональных чисел: "))

# Перебираем все возможные пары числителей и знаменателей
for numerator in range(1, height+1):
    for denominator in range(1, height+1):
        # Проверяем, что числитель и знаменатель не равны высоте
        if numerator + denominator != height:
            continue
        # Проверяем, что дробь несократимая
        if gcd(numerator, denominator) != 1:
            continue
        # Проверяем, что дробь лежит между 0 и 1
        if numerator/denominator > 1 or numerator/denominator < 0:
            continue
        # Если все условия выполнены, печатаем дробь
        print(f"{numerator}/{denominator}")
```

Comment: Если *n* не велико, то можно соорудить решето по всем простым делителям *n*. Какой диапазон у *n*?

Comment: Если *n* так велико что решето не лезет в память, можно сделать сегментированное решето.

Comment: Теоретически, диапазон может быть любым. Мы ведь заранее не знаем, какую высоту пожелает ввести пользователь.

Comment: Для решета понадобится разложить *n* на множители. Но разложение займёт не больше времени чем печать. Так что я за решёта.

Comment: Сегментированное решето? Что за зверь? С чем едят? Где об этом почитать?

Comment: Обычно решето имеет диапазон `[1, n]`. Сегментированное состоит из сегментов `[1, m)`, `[m, 2m)`, `[2m, 3m)`, ... . Сегменты обрабатываются последовательно. `m` выбирается как минимум из доступной памяти и `n^0.5`.

Comment: `if numerator/denominator > 1 or numerator/denominator < 0:` - ну и условие... К тому же, не в том месте стоит.

Comment: `for numerator in range(1, height):` -> `for numerator in range(1, height // 2 + 1):`. И в цикле убрать условия на величину дроби.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как было сказано в комментариях, можно идти не до `height + 1`, а до `height // 2 + 1`, тогда можно будет убрать проверку на то, что число лежит в `(0, height]`. Также лучше использовать `math.gcd`, он быстрее вашей реализации, т.к. он написан на `c`.

```
n = int(input())

for x in range(1, n // 2 + 1):
    if math.gcd(x, n - x) == 1:
        print(x, n - x)
```

Еще можно заменит `n - x`, на просто `n`. Получаем `math.gcd(x, n) == 1`.

В итоге:

```
n = int(input())

for x in range(1, n // 2 + 1):
    if math.gcd(x, n) == 1:
        print(x, n - x)
```

Если посмотреть на реализую [функции Эйлера](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0):

```
k = 0
for x in range(1, k):
    if math.gcd(x, k) == 1:
        k += 1
```

Различия только в диапозоне, и в том что в одном мы ищем пары, а во втором подсчитывается количество. Исходя из их сходство, вероятно, надо будет посмотреть на эффективную реализацию функции Эйлера

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант, объединил условия. Ещё проверяю ручками

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

height = int(input("Введите высоту рациональных чисел: "))

for numerator in range(1, height):
    denominator = height - numerator
    if gcd(numerator, denominator) == 1 and 0 < numerator/denominator < 1:
        print(f"{numerator}/{denominator}")

input("Нажмите Enter для выхода")
```